# How to add links to the table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have this file called jsonkategoria.json with categories names and links. I want to display these in a table. Somehow (I'm begginer in jQuery programing) my table displays names only. I think the problem may be within the quotes  in  tag. [This is how the table looks in browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMllq.png) There's no link to the page. I've tried many options with adding each line separately (I mean :

```
categories_data += '<a href='; 
categories_data += '"'; 
categories_data += value.links;
```

etc.)

Here's my jQuery code:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON("jsonkategoria.json", function(data){
                    var categories_data = '';
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        categories_data += '<tr>';
                        categories_data += '<a href="'+value.link+'" >';
                        categories_data += '<td>'+value.nazwa+'</td>';
                        categories_data += '</a>';
                        categories_data += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('#categories_tab').append(categories_data);
                });
            });
```

Comment: The immediate child of a table row must be either a `<th>` or a `<td>`. `<a>` is an invalid child of table row, and so the browser attempts to be smart and make sense out of the broken markup. In your case, the browser is simply tripping the `<a></a>` tags out.

Comment: either you got to put an anchor in each cell or add an onclick handler to the tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("jsonkategoria.json", function(data){
      var categories_data = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
          categories_data += '<tr>';
          categories_data += '<td><a href="' + value.link + '" >' + value.nazwa + '</a></td>';
          categories_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#categories_tab').append(categories_data);
  });
});
```

You misplaced `anchor` tag, it should be inside `td` not outside `td`

Comment: I was struggling with other solution (above) because of CSS styling. When I used your version - now everything looks fine :) Thanks

Comment: Welcome @Alcyone127 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("jsonkategoria.json", function(response){
$.each(response, function (i, value) {
     $('<tr>').append(
     $('<td>').append('<td><a href="' + value.link + '" >' + value.link + '</a></td>'),
     $('<td>').text(value.nazwa).appendTo('#categories_tab');
    });
  });
 });
```